# Struts 2 jQuery Datepicker format issue

Tags: java, jquery, hibernate, struts2, struts2-jquery

I have and entity `user` which is receiving dates form a Struts 2 form using the jQuery plugin for `datepicker`s and whenever I change the date format from `mm/dd/yyy/` to `mm/yyyy` it no longer sets the date correctly anymore even though the user still has to select a `month/day/year` by default with the calendar.

So my question is, is there a work around for this or a way to go about changing how the data is passed from the form to the entity to make this work?

**Form excerpt:**

```jsp
<tr>
  <td style="border: 0px;">Contract Start-1</td>
  <td style="border: 0px;">
    <sj:datepicker name="user.nat_gas_start1" displayFormat="mm/dd/yy" yearRange="20011:2020" value="currentUser.nat_gas_start1"/>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="border: 0px;">Month Shopping For-1</td>
  <td style="border: 0px;">
    <sj:datepicker name="user.nat_gas_end1" displayFormat="mm/yy" yearRange="20011:2020" value="currentUser.nat_gas_end1"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**Entity excerpt (dates are Java SQL):**

```
public void setNat_gas_start3(Date nat_gas_start3) {
    this.nat_gas_start3 = nat_gas_start3;
}

public Date getNat_gas_end1() {
    return nat_gas_end1;
}
```

The form executes and action which over writes the existing values and passes them into the database via Hibernate. It was previously working until I switched the end date format to the `mm/yyyy` format.

Comment: If date is converted incorrectly then use custom converter.

Comment: that's what I'm thinking I might have to do but I was trying to avoid having to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not switch the date format, the date format 'mm/yyyy' is treated incorrectly, as a result wrong date value is converted to the action. These are  examples of correct date formats:

```
<sj:datepicker value="today" id="date3" name="date3" displayFormat="dd.mm.yy" label="Today" />
<sj:datepicker value="yesterday" id="date4" name="date4" displayFormat="mm/dd/yy" label="Yesterday" />
<sj:datepicker value="tomorrow" id="date5" name="date5" displayFormat="DD, d MM yy" label="Tomorrow" />
<sj:datepicker value="2004-08-14" id="date6" name="date6" displayFormat="d M, yy" label="String Value" />
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the date be displayed like that 'mm/yyyy' after selection but still have it be pulled in correctly without having to write a custom converter?

Comment: Write the string setter and parse the date string manually, but with that format you have missed a day.

Comment: that's what I'm gonna end up doing I'm just gonna read it in as a string and then parse it to a date and just set the day to 1 because for this it really doesn't matter what day of the month I have.