# change struts 2 datepicker format

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2

I have a struts2 form which contains some dates as inputs. The date in the datepicker are presented in US format (mm/dd/yyyy).However, I want to customize this format to dd/mm/yyyy.

Here's the initial code :

```
 <s:textfield type="date"  cssClass="form-control" name="ueDate" required="required">                                            

 </s:textfield>
```

I have already tried to add:

```
format="dd/mm/yyyy" and displayFormat="dd/mm/yyyy"
```

but non of theme worked so far.

Here is a capture of current datepicker
[image: tr]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17633303/573032

Comment: That's not really the problem I'm facing..